# How I can pass data from a database to a "select tag" in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I new on ASP.NET, and I trying to set data in `select` from `query` when the page load

This is mi table:

**Area**

```
ID_Area|ID_Formula|Nombre
```

Now my code

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label >Nombre de Area</label>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="area" CssClass="form-control" required="true"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Formula asociada</label>
                 <select id="Select1" runat="server" name="D1"> </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Button ID="btn_login" OnClick="docreatearea" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" Text="Guardar" runat="server"/>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack){
        string query = @"SELECT * FROM FORMULA";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BancoEstadoConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            comand.Fill(ds, "Area");
            conn.Open();
            Select1.DataSource = ds;
            Select1.DataTextField = "Nombre";
            Select1.DataValueField = "Nombre";
            Select1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem apears in the `fill function` because doenst exist in `SqlCommand object`

How can I do that o fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a SqlDataAdapter to fill your DataSet:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BancoEstadoConnectionString"].ToString()))
    {
        SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        conn.Open();

        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Authors");

        Select1.DataSource = ds;
        Select1.DataTextField = "au_fname";
        Select1.DataValueField = "au_fname";
        Select1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**au_fname** does not exist in your name. Change it to a valid column name in your table.

Comment: It would be something like ``Select1.DataTextField = "Nombre";`` ??

Comment: Yes, and look at the other answer regarding DataAdapter, you need a DataAdapter to fill your DataSet

Answer (score 0):

The Fill command is in the SqlDataAdapter class.

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

User below code for your page load method

```
if(!IsPostBack){
    string query = @"SELECT * FROM FORMULA";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BancoEstadoConnectionString"].ToString()))
    {
        SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        adp.Fill(ds);

        Select1.DataSource = ds;
        Select1.DataTextField = "au_fname";
        Select1.DataValueField = "au_fname";
        Select1.DataBind();
    }
}
```